# Mixamo Fuse Unity eyelashes not correct

Tags: unity, rigging, unity-shader-graph

I created a character in Adobe Fuse, sent it to Mixamo for rigging with blendshapes and downloaded the fbx for unity file.
Below is how the character eyelashes appear in Fuse..

[image]

However, when I imported the fbx file and pulled it in my scene, the eyelashes appear as a piece of block. How do I fix this?

[image]

EDIT: It seems like the eyelashes are messed up due to Mixamo, there is no issue with Unity import. It happens when the Fuse character is sent to Mixamo for rigging and downloaded from there. When I opened the downloaded fbx file in Windows 3dViewer, it appeared with messes up eyelashes as shown below.

[image]

EDIT: Added the texture/material option pane, material settings and import settings for albedo texture in Unity below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably you made sure their material is set up to draw with transparency? Show us how you've configured the material and texture the eyelashes use.

Comment: All I did was open fuse application and create the character using customize head/torso/etc. options that are present there. No medlling with textures or material whatsoever. They are just whatever the default textures are, and appear fine within fuse. In fact, I do not see any option to set the texture/material for eye. updated the question with the screenshot. @DMGregory please see the screenshot

Comment: Please show us how the material is configured **in Unity**, since that's where you're observing a problem.

Comment: I have set up all the materials as opaque, except the one for eyelashes which is transparent. Nevertheless, the lashes are appearing messes up if i just open the fbx file in windows 3d viewer, ever before I could import to Unity.

Comment: Does your albedo texture contain alpha transparency? How are its import settings configured?

Comment: Added the import settings for Albedo @DMGregory

Comment: Looks like "Aloha is transparency" isn't checked, but that shouldn't cause this particular problem.

Comment: I tried checking it, nothing changed.